# How to index tweet as soon as it is posted?

Tags: php, api, twitter

Is there a way to know that a user posted a tweet as soon as he does it? Maybe Twitter can ping your app or something?

What if I have a user base of 100.000 users? It's hard to check constantly all.

Thank you,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the Streaming API for this case. This is exactly what this does, you open a firehose and Twitter pings your application with new tweets every time there is an update based on your query. If your using PHP, you can make implementing the streaming API easier by using the [140 framework](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/).

from streaming API method doc

> The default access level allows up to 400 track keywords, 5,000 follow
>   userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes. If you need elevated
>   access to the Streaming API, you should explore our partner providers
>   of Twitter data [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Streaming API, specificially user streams: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams

Comment: What if I have a database of 100.000 users? Is it still working?